# Pentaho Data Integration setVariable and getVariable issue

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I have a job with following transformation in a line:

1) Start

2) calculate_variables

3) use_variables

[image]

**calculate_variables transformation**

This transformation has 3 steps:

**step 1:** "`Table input`" step which reads single value `my_date` from database

**step 2:** "`Add constant values`" step which declares a date constant `some_date`

**step 3:** "`Script Values / Mod`" step which is a javascript/java step which uses `my_date` and `some_date` to do some calculations and come up with two result variables. One is a number as a string and other is date as a string. At the end of the javascript step I have below statements:

```
setVariable("NUMBER_VARIABLE", calculatedNumber, "r");
setVariable("DATE_VARIABLE", calculatedDate, "r");
```

My understanding in Pentaho is limited. But from what I know, this creates two new variables `NUMBER_VARIABLE` and `DATE_VARIABLE` and makes them available to every other jobs and transformation as they are set to `root`.

**use_variables transformation**

This is where I want to use the variables `NUMBER_VARIABLE` and `DATE_VARIABLE`.

**Step 1:** I have "`Generate Rows`" as the first step in this transformation.

I want to use `NUMBER_VARIABLE` as the `Limit` of Generate Rows. So I have put `${NUMBER_VARIABLE}` in the Limit field.

**Step 2:** "`Generate Rows`" feeds into a javascript/java step where I am trying to use the DATE_VARIABLE as below:

```
var sdf = java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",locale);
var myDate = sdf.parse(DATE_VARIABLE.getString());
```

My expectation is that this setup should work fine. If `NUMBER_VARIABLE` is 100, the limit for `Generate Rows` in next transformation should get set to 100, it should generate 100 rows and then the javascript step should run for those 100 rows and `DATE_VARIABLE` should be available inside javascript step for use.

When I run this job, `calculate_variables` transformation runs successfully. But, `use_variables` transformation fails with the following error:

```
2018/09/19 10:02:40 - Calculate Dimension Attributes.0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.1-37, build 1 from 2016-12-21 12.39.46 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2018/09/19 10:02:40 - Calculate Dimension Attributes.0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.1-37, build 1 from 2016-12-21 12.39.46 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleValueException: 
2018/09/19 10:02:40 - Calculate Dimension Attributes.0 - Javascript error: 
2018/09/19 10:02:40 - Calculate Dimension Attributes.0 - ReferenceError: "DATE_VARIABLE" is not defined. (script#9)
```

I am unable to figure out why this is happening and what can I do to fix this issue.

**Edit 1:**

When I attach a "`Write to log`" step to my `Generate rows` and try to log the variables as:

```
__________________________ the variables are _______________________

number variable=${NUMBER_VARIABLE}
date variable=${DATE_VARIABLE}
____________________________________________________________________
```

And then when I run the job, I do get the variables printed successfully:

```
2018/09/19 10:11:20 - Write to log.0 - __________________________ the variables are _______________________
2018/09/19 10:11:20 - Write to log.0 - 
2018/09/19 10:11:20 - Write to log.0 - number variable=8662
2018/09/19 10:11:20 - Write to log.0 - date variable=2000-01-01
2018/09/19 10:11:20 - Write to log.0 - ____________________________________________________________________
```

This means the variables are correctly set and are available in the next transformation. Why is the javascript step complaining about it?

Comment: Happy for that you solved it. Please answer to your question (rather than editing the question). This  in order to really help somebody stuck like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. :)

The issue was the way I was using the variable in Javascript step.

I changed to:

```
var myDateVariable=getVariable("DATE_VARIABLE","");
var sdf = java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",locale);
var myDate = sdf.parse(myDateVariable);
```

Hope this helps somebody stuck like me!

Comment: Must be tested, SimpleDateFormat, it is not thread safe, not necessary but possible error values if huge amount of data are processed.

Comment: @simar: Shouldn't be an issue as my DATE_VARIABLE is a constant to be used by everything...